# USB-Flash-drive no longer enumerated by system, how to repair

Tags: dd, usb-drive, gparted, partition-table, lsusb

One of my memory sticks has stopped being usable. It's not that old, and has a fairly low R/W life used. But any attempt to format or write to it seems impossible now.

When inserted it creates a new file under /dev/bus/usb/00x where x is the USB slot number.
It also creates a /dev/sda and /dev/sg0 file.
But it kicks out many errors and end with "unable to enumerate USB device", at which point it removes all the /dev entries.

This makes it impossible to use gparted, dd, fdisk (& friends), or even writing to the raw port file.

If you time it right lsusb reports this: "Bus 003 Device 000: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Glide".

I'f attempted to access the device while the system still sees it with the various programs that would let me repartition of format it. But it's useless. While the program will "See" it and attempt to do something, the OS inevitably pulls the device out from under them, and they fail.

I'd hate to have to toss a fairly new device just because it needs a new formating, maybe a low level formatting, or a new partition table.

I'm running Linux Mint 20. But I've tried the stick on multiple PCs with like results.

This is a sample of the dmesg output:

```
[133514.320240] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[133514.470749] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5575, bcdDevice= 1.26
[133514.470761] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[133514.470765] usb 3-3: Product: Cruzer Glide
[133514.470769] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[133514.470771] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: [redacted]
[133514.471281] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[133514.471544] scsi host2: usb-storage 3-3:1.0
[133515.493220] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Glide     1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[133515.493590] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[133515.494704] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 125031680 512-byte logical blocks: (64.0 GB/59.6 GiB)
[133515.495625] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[133515.495629] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[133515.495999] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[133546.508783] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[133551.876137] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[133567.486413] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[133567.722470] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[133572.865798] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[133588.487499] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[133588.723688] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[133593.994782] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[133599.373607] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[133599.609729] usb 3-3: reset high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[133604.752327] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[133610.134539] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[133610.242599] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 27
[133610.262642] print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[133610.262649] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262666] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[133610.262668] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262746] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262759] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262782] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262788] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262796] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[133610.262806] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262811] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262824] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262829] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262841] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262846] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262858] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262862] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262869] Dev sda: unable to read RDB block 0
[133610.262879] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262883] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262896] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262900] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[133610.262941] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 24 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[133610.262946] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 3, async page read
[133610.262973]  sda: unable to read partition table
[133610.263154] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[133610.263161] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[133610.263167] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[133610.263182] sda: detected capacity change from 125031680 to 0
[133610.263188] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[133610.478662] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[133615.637017] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[133631.262274] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[133631.506501] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[133636.899919] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[133652.511757] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[133652.619765] usb usb3-port3: attempt power cycle
[133653.272101] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[133658.529503] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[133663.906162] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[133664.141913] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[133669.282862] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[133674.663634] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[133674.771732] usb usb3-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```